# Difference between NgChartsModule vs ChartsModule from 'ng2-charts'

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

At the moment I am developing a dashboard using Angular 13 + NG 2 charts. Want to know the difference between,

import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

Comment: Perhaps, you should search the docs for the chart library to see if that gives you any clues.

Answer (score 0):

ChartsModule are not available in the 3.0+ version. I think we have to import the NGChartsModule as per documentation.